# AWS: VPC, Subnets, NACLs, Security Groups, IGWs, Route Tables, Etc

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, subnet, aws-security-group, routetable

I've watched hours upon hours of tutorials and have read until my eyes were about to bleed, but I just cannot seem to grasp how Amazon VPCs are working. I've created and deleted entire VPC environments with EC2 instances various times following tutorials, but as soon as I go to create one w/out the tutorial, I'm lost.

I'm trying to come up with an analogy to help me to better understand. What I have so far is something like this:

> A *VPC* is like a **Club**. At the front of the club, you have an
> **Entrance**, the *IGW*. Inside the Club, you have different areas; the **General Area** which would be the *public subnet* and the
> **Management Area** which is the *private subnet*.
>
> Within the **General Area** you would have a **Dance Floor/Bar** which
> would equate to an *EC2 Instance* and a **Receiving Bay** where management
> can receive deliveries and whatnot from the outside world, the *NAT*.
>
> Then in the **Management Area** you'd have an **Office**, another *EC2
> Instance*, and your **Inventory** which is like your *RDS*.

I think that's a somewhat accurate analogy so far, but once I start to try and work in the SGs, NACLs, RTs, etc, I realize that I'm just not grasping it all.

Can anyone help me with finishing this analogy or supply a better analogy? I'm at my wits' end.

Comment: If you have some traditional networking background, you can use that as an analogy. The VPC stuff almost map perfectly to the traditional networking tools and equipments. I personally think the club analogy just makes things more confusing.

Comment: I don't have any traditional background in networking, this is something I have to learn for my work. I'm just trying to wrap my head around how everything is interconnected. As soon as I think I'm starting to get it, I realize that I'm just as confused as ever. To top it off, I don't know what I don't know which is making it that much more difficult to research =/

Answer (score 4):

Rather than using analogies, let's use **the network you already have at home**.

Within your home, you probably have a **Router** and various devices connected to the router. They might be directly connected via ethernet cables (eg a PC), or they might be connected via wifi (eg tablets, phones, Alexa). Your home network is like a VPC. Your various devices connect to the network and all of the devices can talk to each other.

You also have some sort of box that connects your router to the **Internet**. This might be a cable modem, or a fibre router or (in the old days) a telephone connection. These boxes connect your network (VPC) to the Internet and are similar in function to an **Internet Gateway**. Without these boxes, your network would not be able to communicate with the Internet. Similarly, without an Internet Gateway, a VPC cannot communicate with the Internet.

Some home routers allow you to broadcast a **Guest network** in addition to your normal network. This is a network where you can give guests a password, but they can't access your whole network -- this is good for security, since they can't snoop around your network to try and steal your data. This is similar in concept to having a **separate subnet** -- there are two networks, but routing rules (NACLs) block the traffic between them to improve security.

A home router typically blocks incoming access to your devices. This means that people on the Internet cannot access your computer, printer, devices, etc. This is good, since there are many bots on the Internet always trying to hack into devices on your network. However, the home router allows **outbound requests** from your devices to the Internet (eg a website) and it is smart enough to allow the responses to **come back into the network**. This is equivalent to a **Security Group**, which has rules that determine what Inbound and Outbound requests are permitted. Security Groups are **stateful**, which means they automatically allow return traffic even if it is not specifically listed. The difference is that the router is acting as the Security Group, whereas in an Amazon VPC it is possible to assign a Security Group to *each individual resource* (like having a router on each resource).

That doesn't cover all the capabilities of an Amazon VPC, but it should give you an idea of how the network actually behaves.